# Solution for Moment problem

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, probability-distributions

I want to invert a sequence of moments and find a function f(x) satisfying:
$$m_r=\int x^{r}f(x) dx=\int x^{r} dF(x)$$

The sequence of moments is given by:

$m_{2s+1}=0$

$m_{2s}=\sum_{k=1}^{s}\binom{2s-k}{s}\frac{k}{2s-k}d^{k}\frac{(d-1)^{s+1-k}}{d-c}\left(1-\left(\frac{c-1}{d-1}\right)^{s-k+1}\right),$

for each $s\geq0$. Here $d > c\geq3$ are fixed integers.

I found for this problem that
$\omega:=\sup\left\{ |x|:0<F(x)<1\right\} =2\sqrt{d-1},$ so we can replace
$\int x^{r}f(x) dx$ by $\int^{\omega}_{-\omega } x^{r}f(x) dx$

I am trying to expand f(x) using Chebyshev polynomials in order to find its coefficients, but I was unsuccessful simplifying the expressions.

Do you know how I could get a closed form for f(x)?

Comment: Step 1: see if you can find some "closed form" for the moments. Step 2: hope to apply http://mathoverflow.net/questions/79868/what-does-mellin-inversion-really-mean/79925#79925

Comment: Any linear recurrence for the moments may also be of use

Comment: @PietroMajer The recurrence is nonlinear. Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: Try to deduce an equation for $f$ from the recurrence; if you add it I'll see.

Comment: Thanks @PietroMajer. I put the reduced problem with a recurrence below.

Comment: what is the interval  where the measure is supported? is it the above $[-\omega,\omega]$? (a  good starting point would be to get rid of some constants, and renormalize e.g. in $[-1,1]$ )

Comment: Yes that is the support. I normalized to [-1,1], however the expressions just don't simplify.

Comment: The expressions appear in this question [http://mathoverflow.net/questions/258232/closed-expression-for-the-sum]

Answer (score 2):

I solved it partially, but it remains to solve for
$m_{2s}=\sum_{k=1}^s k {2\,s-k-1\choose s-1}\left({\frac{d}{c-1}} \right) ^{k-1},$
where $d>c\geq3$ are integers.

Besides, $m_{2s}$ satisfy the recurrence relation
 $\left( {d}^{2}+{d}^{2}s \right) m_{2s} + \left( {c}^{2}s-
2\,s  c  +s-  d s  c  +
  d  s \right) m_{2(s+1)} ={\frac { \left( c-1
 \right) ^{2}{4}^{s}\Gamma  \left( s+1/2 \right) }{\sqrt {\pi }\Gamma 
 \left( s \right) }}$